# iOS Instant Messenger service: Best way to to check for new messages?

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, instant-messaging

If i were to make an instant messenger for iOS, how would i go about checking for new messages?

Would it involve continuous checks to a web service to see if there are any new messages (e.g. every few seconds), or some kind of live feed with the web service to update the app immediately?

Comment: @RogielSulzbach i'm thinking more about if they're in a conversation, and someone sends them a message, how to get it to update the screen straight away, as apposed to e.g. pressing a refresh button

Comment: You can send silent push notifications that prompt the client to run an api call without alerting the user that anything has happened

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html

Comment: @JeffN like doing an ajax request every few seconds?

Comment: Well when one user sends, there will be a destination, set your backend to send a silent push to that destination user, which updates the destination user's stream.

Comment: iMessage is based purely on push,. If the app is the front, only notification (in terms of API, not user interface) is dispatched, and you can load the message based on some ID you include on the push notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSStream` and `CSStream` to communicate from within your `iOS` apps to a `TCP` server. Keeping an open socket connection with your server will allow the server to send you a notification about the new message instantly. You will need an output stream (`NSOutputStream`) and an input stream (`NSInputStream`) so you can manage outgoing and incoming communications easily and in parallel.

Some useful links:

[Introduction to Stream Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188i)

[How To Create A Socket Based iPhone App and Server](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

[Tutorial: Building A Simple iOS TCP Socket Based App Client And Server](http://maniacdev.com/2011/06/tutorial-building-a-simple-ios-tcp-socket-based-app-client-and-server)

Comment: Thanks Reecon, do you know of any good articles that cover this?

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer with some useful links. In one of my apps we used a socket communication with the server. It was used to get instant updates about event that happened in the social network, It was working really well. And it was much faster and reliable than silent push notifications.